# Slipping in non conditional code between if thens

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I move to the next if in an If-Then chain, I want to increment k. Let me show you below. I put some brackets encapsulating what should be in "Then". I know this can be done with nested If-Elses but I'm hoping to find a way with ElseIfs for readability.

```
 If (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "LTD") [Then
                    wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1]

k=k+1

                ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "STD" Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "Workman's Comp") <> 0) [Then
                    wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1]
k=k+1
                
                ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "Vacation") [Then
                    wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1]
k=k+1
                
                ElseIf (InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FMLA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FFCRA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FPML") <> 0) Then
                    wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1
```

I want it logically to be like this:

```
Function Demo()
k = 1
If (a) Then
'''stuff

Else
    k = k + 1
    If (b) Then
    '''stuff
    Else
        k = k + 1
        If (c) Then
        '''stuff
        Else
            k = k + 1
            Etc
        
End Function
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how 'if then elseif ' works. Each if/elseif is evaluated in turn, if an if/elseif is satisfied then the code in that block is executed and the code then jumps to the end if.  No other elseifs are evaluated.

Comment: If you want to know which block is executed then put k=1, k=2,k=3 etc instead of k=k+1

Comment: After each conditional is falsed, I want it to increment. So if the 3rd one is true and k starts at 1, k would be 3. If the 4th is true, k would be 4. Etc.

Comment: Does k always start as 1 ?

Comment: I can't figure out the point by doing this. Since the code won't be changed while being executed, you don't need to increase `k` one by one. You can simply put `k=1` or `k=k+1` in the first `elseif` block, and `k=2` or `k=k+2` in the second `elseif` block, etc.

Comment: It's a QOL thing for when I insert a new row or column. Then instead of changing every instance of k I just slip the new conditional in along with a k+1 and everything gets kicked down the line

Answer (score 0):

Only code inside the true condition block is executed. Maybe you want something like

```vb
n = 0
If (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "LTD") Then
    n = 1
ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "STD" _
    Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "Workman's Comp") <> 0) Then
    n = 2
ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "Vacation") Then
    n = 3
ElseIf (InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FMLA") <> 0 _
    Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FFCRA") <> 0 _
    Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FPML") <> 0) Then
    n = 4
Endif

If n > 0 Then
   k = k + n - 1
   wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code would be executed block by block, there is no need to increase `k` after each `false` condition.

```
If (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "LTD") Then
    k = 1
ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "STD" Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "Workman's Comp") <> 0) Then
    k = 2
ElseIf (wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "Vacation") Then
    k = 3
ElseIf (InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FMLA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FFCRA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FPML") <> 0) Then
    k = 4
End If

wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1
```

However if you really need to do this, maybe the code below fits you. I don't recommend though.

```
Private k

Private Function testIncrement(bool As Boolean) As Boolean
    If Not bool Then k = k + 1
    testIncrement = bool
End Function

Private Sub yourMainCodeHere()

    k = 1

    If testIncrement(wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "LTD") Then
    ElseIf testIncrement(wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "STD" Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "Workman's Comp") <> 0) Then
    ElseIf testIncrement(wsD.Cells(j, 3) = "Vacation") Then
    ElseIf testIncrement(InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FMLA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FFCRA") <> 0 Or InStr(wsD.Cells(j, 3), "FPML") <> 0) Then
    End If

    wsNS.Cells(i, k) = wsNS.Cells(i, k) + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other suggestions - if you really want this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim a, k
    a = "c"
    k = 0
    
    If plusOne(k) And a = "a" Then
    
    ElseIf plusOne(k) And a = "b" Then
    
    ElseIf plusOne(k) And a = "c" Then

    ElseIf plusOne(k) And a = "d" Then
    
    End If

    Debug.Print k '3

End Sub

Function plusOne(ByRef i)
    i = i + 1
    plusOne = True
End Function
```